# Universal Windows 10 - How to add button in title bar like Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

I use Extend View into titlebar like this:

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

And my Xaml code is:

```
 <Page
x:Class="ProjectX.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ProjectX"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid Background="#263238" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" RequestedTheme="Dark">
        <TextBlock Text="Title Bar" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Width="50" Height="32" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtTest" Text="AAAAAAAAAA" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
</Grid>
```

The button can't click. Help me!

Comment: Where have you put the xaml code?

Comment: See the [TitleBar sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TitleBar/) for a demonstration of how to put controls in the title bar.

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you :D

Comment: Note also that you should use the title bar metrics rather than hard coding 32. Otherwise your title bar will not match the system's idea of the title bar area.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the back button

```
using Windows.UI.Core;
var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a full description here: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/easily-manage-the-title-bar-in-windows-10-apps/

In short, what you miss is that you must call a Window.Current.SetTitleBar method to set that only that control is used to handle window operations, while other controls will receive input regularly.